# My WebDriverWait is returning a "dict" instead of the required element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to use Selenium with Gauge to grab data from a web page. I wrote the following code, using `wait_for_element`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from step_impl.mixins.exception import MixinException

class MixinSelector(MixinException):

    def __init__(self, driver=None):
        super(MixinSelector, self).__init__(driver)
        self.wait_for_element_time = 60

    def wait_for_elem(self, by, locator_string):
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,self.wait_for_element_time)
                      .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, 
                       locator_string)))
            print(element)
            print(type(element))  
            return element
        except TimeoutException:
            self.fail_test('failed')
        except:
            raise
```

This, however, results in a `dict` instance, as shown by the debug `print`s:

```
{'ELEMENT': '0.8884832448581164-1'}
<class 'dict'>
```

I call the function like so:

```
self.wait_for_elem(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#baseWebLayoutContainerID')
```

This is a problem because I need the result to be a web element I can use in several other functions. How can I get that result?

Comment: What *exactly* did you want to get back instead? How is that different, and why is this result not usable for you? What exactly do you mean by "an element"? Is there a particular class that you wanted an instance of, for example?

Comment: I edited your question to [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/kind-reminder-to-remove-noise) and explicitly ask a question. Please see [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: a web element, I realize now I didn't specify it

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We can't see the problem like this because, among other possible issues, `EC` is not defined locally.

Comment: Done. I'm sorry about it, kinda new. Will read the "how to ask" and its documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't expect a web element getting back from WebDriverWait, instead put another line after WebDriverWait to get the web element, see below code

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, locator_string)))
element = driver.find_element(by, locator_string) 
return element
```

it works fine with me as you can see in the below image

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Ahmed! I did try that one a couple hours ago... same result. the element's still a dict

Comment: very weird, I attached an image showing that it's working.

Comment: Just saw the image... huh, guess the issue is somewhere else? I use this line: element = self.driver.find_element(by, locator_string) but the result doesn't change. Could it be my driver or something like that?

Comment: maybe!! I assume you are using chrome, please update your chrome browser by clicking on the triple dots at the top right then help then about google chrome then it will be updated automatically to version 95, after relaunching it, go to https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=95.0.4638.17/ and download the newest driver. then make another try, please let me know what you got

Comment: Oh... oh my god that was it. You're my hero Ahmed! Thank you so very much! I spent over 10 hours trying to figure that out...

Comment: Sorry I can't give u the arrow up, I have to little rep! Still, you're the best!